# Issue with exporting a list of data more than 50 records

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel

I have a page where i am displaying customers records in b-table, but i have applied pagination due to which only 50 records are being displayed on a single page, then page 2 , page 3 and so on...

I have huge amount of data so i need to apply pagination , now whenever i am fetching the data of first page in excel using export function, it is fetching data of just 50 records.i.e. and for second page again separately.

Can you guys help me to correct this? i want to export records of all customers in a single file without pagination concept but i dont want to remove.

```
<template>
    <div class="page-wrapper mt-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Customers</h3>
                            <div class="card-options">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="exportFile">
                                    Export
                                </button>
                                <a type="button" @click="createCustomer" class="btn btn-success">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"></line><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line></svg>
                                    New Customer
                                </a> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body border-bottom py-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                    <div class="input-icon mb-3">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search…" @input="getcustomers" v-model="search">
                                        <span class="input-icon-addon">
                                        <!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/search -->
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" /><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" /></svg>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " @click="getcustomers">Filter</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <b-table striped hover :items="customers" :fields="fields" responsive>
                                <template #cell(first_name)="row">
                                    <router-link :to="{path: '/customers/' + row.item.id}">{{ row.item.first_name}}</router-link>
                                </template>
                                <template #cell(last_name)="row">
                                    <router-link :to="{path: '/customers/' + row.item.id}">{{ row.item.last_name}}</router-link>
                                </template>
                            </b-table>
                            
                            <b-pagination
                                @change="handlePageChange"
                                v-model="currentPage"
                                :total-rows="rows"
                                :per-page="perPage"
                                aria-controls="my-table"
                            ></b-pagination>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <CreateCustomer @exit="getcustomers"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CreateCustomer from '~/components/Customers/CreateCustomer.vue';
import writeXlsxFile from 'write-excel-file';
export default {
    name: 'customersPage',
    components: { CreateCustomer},
    head() {
        return {
            title: 'customers - TopLimo'
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',
            user: this.$auth.user,
            customers: [],
            fields: [
                'id',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'phone_number',
            ],
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 50,
            rows: 0,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getcustomers();
    },
    methods: {
        getcustomers() {
            this.$axios.$get('/api/admin/customers?page=' + this.currentPage + '&search=' + this.search)
                .then(response => {
                    this.customers = response.data;
                    this.perPage = response.per_page;
                    this.currentPage = response.current_page;
                    this.rows = response.total;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.$toast.error('Error fetching Customers');
                });
        },
        exportFile: function () {
            console.log('export fun called');
            const schema = [
                {
                    column: 'ID',
                    type: Number,
                    value: customer => customer.id
                },
                {
                    column: 'FirstName',
                    type: String,
                    value: customer => customer.first_name
                },
                {
                    column: 'LastName',
                    type: String,
                    value: customer => customer.last_name
                },
                {
                    column: 'Email',
                    type: String,
                    value: customer => customer.email
                },
                {
                    column: 'Phone Number',
                    type: String,
                    value: customer => customer.phone_number
                },
            ];

            writeXlsxFile(this.customers, {
                schema,
                fileName: 'customers.xlsx'
            })
        },
        handlePageChange(page) {
            this.currentPage = page;
            this.getcustomers();
        },
        createCustomer()
        {
            this.$bvModal.show('create-customer');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my controller code

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->search;
        $customers = DB::table('customers')
                        ->when(!empty($search) , function ($query) use ($search) {
                            return $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                            ->orwhere('last_name','like', '%'.$search.'%')
                            ->orwhereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%" .$search. "%' ");
                        })
                        ->paginate(50);
                        
        return $customers;
    }
```

Comment: In your `exportFile` method you call `writeXlsxFile` passing in `this.customers` which only ever contains the current page. Instead of passing in `this.customers`, pass in the result of a separate call to your endpoint to retrieve all customers. Modify the index method in your controller so that it does not apply the `paginate()` method when the request is for `all` customers.

Answer (score -1):

Here in your code you are trying to get the current page data that is why you are getting only 50 records as you mentioned in the paginate(), but if you want all the data to be exported then you may try calling separate endpoint to get all the data without paginate.

You can use the same query you have in index method in controller but without paginate method.